# Expand child on top of other children in a listview using animation

Tags: flutter, animation

It is possible to overlap items over others in a ListView, using an animation as in this [**example**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MjXzu.jpg)

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: @MarianoZorrilla AnimatedContainer, Transform.translate, Overlay.. But I think the biggest difficulty is to expand without pushing the other items.

Comment: @MarianoZorrillam  The closest I got:  https://imgur.com/a/OIePME7

Comment: the items are getting pushed because probably you have not used overlay there.Try using overlay with expansionTile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[UPDATED]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: ExpandHero(),
    );
  }
}

class ExpandHero extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ExpandHeroState createState() => _ExpandHeroState();
}

class _ExpandHeroState extends State<ExpandHero> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.black,
      body: Center(
        child: GestureDetector(
          child: Hero(
            tag: 'flipcardHero',
            child: Container(
              color: Colors.yellow[50],
              height: 50,
              width: 150,
            ),
          ),
          onTap: () {
            Navigator.of(context).push(
              PageRouteBuilder(
                opaque: false,
                pageBuilder: (_, __, ___) => ExpandHeroDetail(id: 'flipcardHero'),
              ),
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ExpandHeroDetail extends StatefulWidget {
  final id;
  ExpandHeroDetail({@required this.id});

  @override
  _ExpandHeroDetailState createState() => _ExpandHeroDetailState();
}

class _ExpandHeroDetailState extends State<ExpandHeroDetail> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
      body: GestureDetector(
        child: Center(
          child: Hero(
            tag: widget.id,
            child: Container(
              color: Colors.yellow[50],
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height/2,
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width/2,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        onTap: () {
          Navigator.pop(context);
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, i will try this

Comment: I did and the result is similar to what you want. Is there a way to limit the size of openBuilder? And how can I make the background transparent? After the end of the animation, the dunco turns black.

Comment: Sorry, i've updated my answer with proper animation, just check